# Issues with removing the EventHandler from within the EventHandler

Tags: c#, event-handling

I added a method to an event but now want to remove that method from being run on those events after some condition:

```
public MyClassConstructor()
{
    otherClassObj.OnMyDataReceived += new EventHandler(analyzeValues);
}
private void analyzeValues(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // finished analysis
    otherClassObj.OnMyDataReceived -= analyzeValues;
}
```

This seems to be crashing the program but I don't understand why.  This is my first C# program.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "crashing the program"? Do you get an exception? What's the exception?

Comment: no, no useful exception.  i could hav been clearer.  the main window just closes and i am no longer running.  the program just seems to exits

Comment: Can you then show the code that runs this code? If you have a console application that is finished after raising this event it will just exit.

Comment: the overall program definitely continues to run.  it's too large to post here right now, sorry.  is there something off about removing yourself from within yourself?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the piece of code you posted...

Comment: Can you post the source code to the event `OnMyDataReceived`?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that your event accessor is [written aproprately](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882534.aspx). It should look something like this:

```
private EventHandler onMyDataReceived;
public event EventHandler OnMyDataReceived
{
    add
    {
        lock (OnMyDataReceived)
        {
            onMyDataReceived += value;
        }
    }
    remove
    {
        lock (OnMyDataReceived)
        {
            onMyDataReceived -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, consider using this to add the event handler:

```
otherClassObj.OnMyDataReceived += analyzeValues;
```

Comment: @DanielMann Sure it does.  When you add or remove a handler it does it by reference.  If he's running it without debugging enabled it can just crash, esp. depending on the version of .NET.

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl sounds interesting! Do you have a link with more info?

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. It seems to work fine to add with `+= new EventHandler(analyzeValues)` and then later remove with just `-= analyzeValues`. Above answer would be relevant as a comment, though, since the method group conversion syntax is nicer.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That was just my gut instinct. I created a test app and it seems to work fine, although I'm not 100% sure about the internals of event binding. Perhaps it has something to do with how the accessor of `OnMyDataReceieved` is written in OP's code.

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility. Although many people use so-called field-like events where the compiler generates the `add` and `remove` accessors automatically.

Comment: add and remove are generated for you by the compiler. You don't need to write them by hand if you don't have any special requirements.

Comment: @WouterdeKort True, but is OP using compiler-generated accessors? It's really not clear to me, and without seeing more code, this is the only thing I can think of to pick apart (that's relevant to the question -- it's possible the real issue is completely unrelated, of course).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your problem is the way you raise your event? You must first copy the current delegate behind the event to a local variable, then chekc it for null, and only *then* invoke it. Like this:

```
var omdr = OnMyDataReceived;
if (omdr != null)
    omdr(this, new EventArgs());
```

Comment: +1 This is one potential problem, as well. Of course it's hard to tell with the provided code.

Answer (score 1):

The following application demonstrates how to subscribe and unsubscribe from an event. You can put this code in a new console application to run it.

It shows that the first time the event is raised, your event handler is called and then unsubscribes itself. The second time, there are no handlers subscribed anymore and nothing happens.

```
using System;
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        Console.WriteLine("Ready..");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    OtherClass otherClassObj = new OtherClass();

    public MyClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Class constructor.. adding event");
        otherClassObj.OnMyDataReceived += analyzeValues;

        Console.WriteLine("Raising event 1");
        otherClassObj.Raise();

        Console.WriteLine("Raising event 2");
        otherClassObj.Raise();
    }

    private void analyzeValues(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event handler");
        Console.WriteLine("Removing event");
        otherClassObj.OnMyDataReceived -= analyzeValues;
    }
}

public class OtherClass
{
    public event EventHandler OnMyDataReceived;

    public void Raise()
    {
        if (OnMyDataReceived != null)
        {
            OnMyDataReceived(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```